# Event based vs polling components

Tags: c#, design-patterns, event-handling, xna

What are the considerations to favor each design?

Suppose i am writing an Input component that gathers input from devices (Mouse, Gamepad, Touch, etc).

One way of designing it would be to supply an API of methods that test a given state at a given point of time (is this button pressed in this frame?)

Another way is to have some other component continuously call this component every frame, checking these things, raising events to notify of things that are happening (for example -- define an event MouseClicked which will be hooked by the API user).

Why would you favor each of these designs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is between a "push" model and a "pull" model, as seen by consuming code. Either works in the context of an input device (at some level, the device is polled by the OS to use as the trigger for an event or simply to set a value that is valid until the next poll). I think the decision to use one or the other is dependent on what is significant; is it clicked now, or has it been clicked? This minor semantic difference can mean major differences in behavior.

If what you are looking for is that a button is pressed as of when you check, then set it up as a polling mechanism. Provide a property that is updated as often as you know how from within your library, that consumers will check in order to determine that a button is being pressed.

If you need to convey that a button was pressed at some time, then set it up as an event, which will "push" this information to its listeners.

Which one you want to use depends on how you structure the program that uses it. A Windows GUI game, where the program is designed from the ground up to simply wait for input, would be best served by an event-based model. A video game, like a side-scroller, where you must know the current state of inputs in order to draw the next frame, might be better served by a polling mechanism.

Quite frankly, in a library like this it would be trivial to set up both scenarios side-by-side; update a property, and then if anyone's listening, shout it out. That way consuming code could push or pull as the user feels necessary for their purpose.

Comment: I currently implemented part of it side by side actually. The only problem is events from this component will never be raised, unless the component is being polled on a regular basis. Or you suggested the component itself will perform the polling?

Comment: I suggest that the component, library, whatever, perform the polling of the actual hardware device or abstraction layer (i.e. DirectInput), and then set properties indicating device state which can in turn be polled by consuming code, and then also fire events when changes to the state of the object occur. So, if I were creating a "Mouse" object representing the state of a mouse, I would have a "LeftButtonDown" boolean property and a "OnLeftButtonDown" event, and my consumers could subscribe to the event or poll the property as they pleased.

Comment: how do you remedy those side-scroller games that rely on input streams wherein a long button press is interpreted as a stream of the same input thus and since the response is not atomic, has a delayed response feel and the new key pressed after the long sequence doesn't seem to be "detected" in time...

Comment: @MywikiWitwiki - Such behaviors are usually a symptom of working at too high a level of abstraction. A keyboard doesn't transmit the letter stream produced by its keys; it provides "down"/"up" messages for each of its keys using a code system. This basic messaging style is then interpreted by the OS, usually as "they pressed this key, so obviously they wanted this letter", but all major OSes retain lower-level "KeyDown"/"KeyUp" messages, and usually the only limitation on sensing keys is hardware-based (some keyboards can't sense certain key combinations due to corners cut in wiring).

Answer (score 1):

May be its better to provide an API where the consumer could specify a callback that could be called with relevant data whenever an event occurs. That way the consumer of your component would not be polling for data.